# gwmi Win32_UserAccount freezes PowerShell

Tags: powershell

So this is the core of my "Get Local Admin Account Info" script:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -ComputerName $server -Credential $Creds -Filter "Domain='$env:USERDOMAIN' AND SID LIKE '%500'"
```

Running this freezes both PS Console and the ISE, requiring Task Manager to kill them.

I understand based on other questions here on stackoverflow that querying Win32_UserAccount can result in a lot of data being pulled over the network. But I would think that specifying a single computer and a single SID would filter that volume of data down to a miniscule amount. I certainly don't have this problem querying other WMI Objects on remote servers.

Am I missing something?

EDIT: This freezes PS too:

```
gwmi win32_useraccount -computername $server "SID LIKE '%500'"
```

Comment: It's quite possible that the provider on the machine you're querying is still returning all domain accounts... i.e., specifying a specific machine might make no difference, unfortunately.

Comment: Durn. There's got to be a way to get one local account off of one server. It's not like I need to query AD or anything.

Comment: If you are looking for a local admin, why are you specifying the domain?

Comment: Not sure how useful this is, but Win32_Desktop returns information only for local "accounts"... what information are you trying to get? Getting associated instances hangs as well, so it looks like that's not any more efficient than querying UserAccount directly.

Comment: Well, gosh, @TheMadTechnician, that's a great question. I used that one-liner because I found it here: [link](http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/active-directory-finding-the-renamed-administrator-account/) and I didn't consider that domain info wasn't necessary.  Although I would need to pass domain creds when querying a system in another domain...

Comment: What i'm trying to get, @Patrick87, is to make sure the built-in Local Admin account is not disabled and that it has been renamed to the corporate standard. I thought this would be a trivial query.

Comment: @JamesBrown It certainly seems like it should be easy. If you know the domain and user name explicitly, you can use "Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/cimv2 -Query "select * from Win32_UserAccount where Domain='*your domain*' and Name='*your username*'"... this works with good performance on my system.

Comment: I've now had chance to do a little testing and so far I've been unable to persuade `win32_useraccount` to return anything but local accounts. Are you running the script against a domain controller by any chance?

Comment: @andyb, I'm not sure if I'm mis-interpreting your first comment, as the only account I'm interested in getting is the Local Administrator account. However, I am certain that my test server is not a DC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to specify the server name as the domain in the query. I.e "Domain='$server' AND SID LIKE '%500'"

This may still perform poorly though. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394507(v=vs.85).aspx

Could also try filtering on LocalAccount property I.e "LocalAccount='$True'"

Comment: That's a big help @andyb. My test run from 2 to 10 seconds, a massive improvement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you could do `domain =` and `name =`, it would be fast, because those are the indexes.

```
# fast
Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "Domain='$env:USERDOMAIN' AND 
  name = 'js2010'"
```

Strangely, specifying localaccount by itself is fast, but not with a name or sid too.

```
# slow (AD joined)
Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "localaccount = 'true' and 
  name = 'js2010'"

# fast
Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "localaccount = 'true'" | 
  where name -eq js2010

# fast
get-wmiobject win32_useraccount -filter "localaccount = 'true'" | 
  where sid -like *500

# fast
get-wmiobject win32_useraccount -filter "domain = '$env:computername' and
  sid like '%500'"
```

There's also a get-localuser:

```
# fast
Get-Localuser | where sid -like *500
```